# Issue in setting fix (freeze) header for the table in IE9?

Tags: html, css

I am created the table with fixed header and scrollable content. And have css as fixedHeader for thead and scrollContent for tbody:

```
thead.fixedHeader tr {
    position: relative;
}
html > body thead.fixedHeader tr {
    display: block;
}

html > body tbody.scrollContent {
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

This is working in mozilla firefox, Chrome and safari except IE. How this problem solves in IE.

Regards,
Girish

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the z-index? This would keep the header on top at all times.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp